# Using variables from earlier in a sequential list of tasks

Tags: python, locust

Let's say I need to first create a company, then create a bunch of employees for that company. I could do this:

```py
from locust import HttpUser, task

class CompanyAPI(HttpUser):
    @task
    def create_company(self):
        resp = self.client.post(
            "/companies",
            json={"name": "Company Name"}
        )
        company_id = resp.json()["id"]

        for i in range(50):
            resp = self.client.post(
                "/employees",
                json={
                    "first_name": f"{i}",
                    "last_name": "Smith",
                    "company": company_id,
                },
            )
```

But it seems like I should be able to break this up into two tasks so that I can create a bunch of these employees in parallel. For that to work tho I'd need to somehow save off the `company_id` in one task, and then use it in subsequent tasks.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get things work ok-ish, I guess, with this code:

```py
from functools import partial
from typing import List, Optional

from gevent import pool as gpool
from locust import HttpUser, SequentialTaskSet, task
from urllib3 import PoolManager

CONNECTION_LIMIT = 10
POOL = gpool.Pool(CONNECTION_LIMIT - 2)


class QuickStartSequence(SequentialTaskSet):
    company_id: Optional[str]
    workplace_id: Optional[str]
    employees: List[str]

    def on_start(self):
        self.company_id = None
        self.workplace_id = None
        self.employees = []

    @task
    def create_company(self):
        resp = self.client.post("/companies", json={"legal_name": "Thunderbolts"})
        self.company_id = resp.json()["id"]

    @task
    def create_workplace(self):
        resp = self.client.post("/workplaces", json={"company": self.company_id})
        self.workplace_id = resp.json()["id"]

    @task
    def create_employees(self):
        def request(_, i: int):
            resp = self.client.post(
                "/employees",
                json={
                    "first_name": "America",
                    "last_name": f"Chavez {i}",
                    "company": self.company_id,
                    "workplaces": [self.workplace_id],
                },
            )
            self.employees.append(resp.json()["id"])

        for i in range(5):
            POOL.spawn(partial(request, i=i), self._parent.environment)
        POOL.join()


class AuthenticatedUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [QuickStartSequence]
    pool_manager = PoolManager(maxsize=CONNECTION_LIMIT, block=True)
```

The connection limit and pool are important because my backing database is only accepting 10 connections at a time.

Because I am using a `SequentialTaskSet` I know that each method will be called in the order it's defined in the code. So I can set things like `self.company_id` in one method and know that it will be set already in the next method.

Then to get parallel execution for the creation of employees, I just need to spawn those requests with a pool executor.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish that, but the most obvious one would be to call `/companies` in a test_start event handler, save it on module or class level and use it in your task.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#test-start-and-test-stop

Heres a starting point (this will reuse the same company id for all Users forever, so probably you'll want to modify it a little, maybe by calling `/companies` again once `i` reaches 50)

```
from locust.runners import MasterRunner
import requests

class CompanyAPI(HttpUser):
    i = -1
    @task
    def create_company(self):  
        i += 1  
        resp = self.client.post(
            "/employees",
            json={
                "first_name": f"{i}",
                "last_name": "Smith",
                "company": self.company_id,
            },
        )

@events.test_start.add_listener
def _(environment, **_kwargs):
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner):
        resp = requests.post(
            "/companies",
            json={"name": "Company Name"}
        )
        CompanyAPI.company_id = resp.json()["id"]
```

For a full example: https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/test_data_management.py

Comment: There's a number of issues with this code and I wasn't able to get it working. For one thing we don't have `self` in the listener function so we can't make a call to `self.client.post()`. This is the code I tried to run.

Comment: ```python
class AuthenticatedUser(HttpUser):
    company_id: Optional[str]

    @task
    def create_company(self):
        resp = self.client.post("/employees", json={"company": self.company_id})


@events.test_start.add_listener
def _(environment, **_kwargs):
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner):
        resp = requests.post("/companies", json={"legal_name": "N"})
        AuthenticatedUser.company_id = resp.json()["id"]
```

Comment: However this results in the error at runtime: `AttributeError: type object 'AuthenticatedUser' has no attribute 'company_id'`

Comment: My bad, I edited the example on my phone trying to adapt it to your particular case. Updated now. (the down side to my update is that the company request will not be logged - there might be other ways to do it, but I dont have time right now)